# Using Pandas to Filter String In Cell with Multiple Values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe, conditional-statements

I am using pandas to filter a data frame using str.contains() but my logic is dropping values that I might want to keep given the string. I don't know how to use Pandas to sort this out.

A sample cell in the excel sheet that I am working with would look like:

Case #1: Don't flag this because there is a different recipient, bob@gmail.com

```
Recipient
---------
joe@work.com, bob@gmail.com, sally@work.com
```

Case #2: Flag this because every recipient contains @work.com

```
Recipient
---------
mike@work.com, taylor@work.com, barbra@work.com
```

I have a situation where I only need it to filter if a specific value occurs. 
For example, if 'Recipient' contains the email joe@work.com, drop this value. But if Recipient column contains 'joe@work.com, bob@gmail.com' (Yes, the values are separated in a comma like that in a single cell.) and keep it. Eventually, this dataframe will be dropped from a final report. So I want to drop everything that just contains @work.com, but don't drop if it contains a @gmail.com, @work.com.

This query below is dropping everything even if the Recipient column contains 'gmail.com'

```
df['EMAIL10'] = df['Type'].str.contains('Email') & df['Type'].str.contains(
                'Tracking | Data') & df[
                                'Recipient'].str.contains('@work.com')
```

Let me know if I need to clarify

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a Boolean Mask that indicates whether or not `all` separate words contain `'@work'`.

First, `split` so that each word is placed into a separate cell, and `explode` will turn this into one big Series, with the index duplicated and pointing back to the index of your original DataFrame. `.str.contains` checks your condition and `all(level=0)` checks whether it's True for every word in a row from your original DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['joe@work.com, bob@gmail.com, sally@work.com', 
                           'mike@work.com, taylor@work.com, barbra@work.com']})

df['all_work'] = df['col'].str.split(', ').explode().str.contains('@work').all(level=0)
```

---

```
print(df)
                                               col  all_work
0      joe@work.com, bob@gmail.com, sally@work.com     False
1  mike@work.com, taylor@work.com, barbra@work.com      True
```

---

For explanation, after split and `explode` we have:

```
df['col'].str.split(', ').explode()

 0       joe@work.com 
 0      bob@gmail.com   # Each item split separately
 0     sally@work.com
 1      mike@work.com
 1    taylor@work.com
 1    barbra@work.com
#|
#Index corresponds to Index of the original DataFrame
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. Fit right in to my existing code. No noticeable slow down. Thank you so much for the explanation. Learned something new about .explode()

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use `explode` then `groupby` to filter out the @work emails

```
print(df)

                                         Recipient
0      joe@work.com, bob@gmail.com, sally@work.com
1  mike@work.com, taylor@work.com, barbra@work.com

s = df['Recipient'].str.split(',').explode()
df['flag removed'] = s[~s.str.contains('@work')].groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
```

---

```
print(df)

                                         Recipient    flag removed
0      joe@work.com, bob@gmail.com, sally@work.com   bob@gmail.com
1  mike@work.com, taylor@work.com, barbra@work.com             NaN
```

you can `.dropna()` to remove the rows with no matches

Answer (score 3):

You should get significant speed benefits if you run string processing within Python:

```
df["all_work"] = [all("@work" in text for text in ent.split(","))
                  for ent in df.col ]

                 col                               all_work
0   joe@work.com, bob@gmail.com, sally@work.com     False
1   mike@work.com, taylor@work.com, barbra@work.com True
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us try something with `str.count`

```
df.col.str.count('@work.com')==df.col.str.count(',').add(1)
Out[148]: 
0    False
1     True
Name: col, dtype: bool
```